# Microsoft.Extensions.Azure register BlobServiceClient when configuration in KeyVault

Tags: .net, configuration, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to register my Azure client dependencies in program.cs (.Net 6)

In program.cs I have:

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
{
    clientBuilder.AddSecretClient(builder.Configuration.GetSection("akeyvaulturl"));
    clientBuilder.AddBlobServiceClient(HowToGetConfigFromKeyVault).WithName("myblobserviceclient");
});
```

The only example I can find is:
`builder.AddBlobServiceClient(Configuration.GetSection("Storage"))`

Which is fine if the blob service client is stored in appsettings.json etc.
But what if my configuration is stored in KeyVault? I can't see anyway of providing keyvault settings as configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I believe, you have to create the `ClientInstance` for the **BlobServiceClient** Class that can bring the dependencies for integration of the Azure Key Vault Configuration libraries in **`.NET Core`**.
- Once the configuration builder instance is created/registered, we have to pass the Configuration values stored in respective Service container such as Azure Key Vault:

```cs
var appOptions = provider.GetService<IOptions<MyApplicationOptions>>();
return new SecretClient(appOptions.Value.KeyVaultEndpoint, credential, options);
```

- Refer to this GitHub [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/README.md#create-named-instances) on .NET Core Integration with Azure Client Libraries which shows the Custom Client Factory of Key Vault Configuration to the blobServiceClient object and [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configuration-options) for more information.

Comment: For anyone insterested, there is a very good example of what I was trying to achieve here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454780/how-to-access-keyvault-secret-values-from-within-startup-cs-for-serilog-sql-sin