# How to access KeyVault Secret values from within Startup.cs (for Serilog SQL Sink)

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, serilog

**Objective**: Setup a SQL Sink, using a Connection String retrieved from an Azure KeyVault

**Issue**: The Secret value is always null/empty - I believe its because the KeyVault values are not yet available at this point in the application lifecycle.

I have confirmed that the Secret value is able to be retrieved from KeyVault later in the app lifecyle i.e in a Controller action method - to the vault is setup correctly.

Does anyone know how to achieve my objective (above)?

Code

```
public class SqlLogOptions
{
    public string AppsettingKey { get; } = "SqlLog";
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

private readonly SqlLogConfig _SqlLogConfig = new SqlLogConfig();

public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    configuration.GetSection(_SqlLogConfig.AppsettingKey).Bind(_SqlLogConfig);
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMapper mapper, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
    //...
}

private void OnStarted()
{
    // Handle configuration that needs to happen once the application has started
    ConfigureLogger();
}

private void ConfigureLogger()
{
    var sinkOptions = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions()
    {
        TableName = "SerilogLogs",
        AutoCreateSqlTable = false
    };

    // Read the connection string from KeyVault Secret
    var connectionString = _SqlLogConfig.ConnectionString;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                       .MinimumLevel.Information()
                       .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, sinkOptions, null, null, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
                       .CreateLogger();

        Log.Logger.Information("***** Connection to SQL logging store could not be established ******");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Connection to SQL logging store could not be established.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `framework` and `version` you are using ?

Comment: @harshitha i'm using .Net 6

Comment: Have you registered the App in the `Azure Active Directory App registrations` and provided required `permissions` in `Azure KeyVault`?

Comment: Hi @Harshitha, as I mentioned in the post, I have confirmed that I can retrieve the secret later in the application lifecycle, so everything is setup correctly in terms of the connection between the App Service and the Key Vault. The issue appears to be the timing...its like I can't read values from the Key Vault from within Startup.cs

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

> How to access KeyVault Secret values from within Startup.cs

`Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` codes are unified into single `Program.cs` file.

We can configure values in `Program.cs` file itself.

Thanks [@azuresdkdocs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/4.0.0/api/index.html) for the Code.

***My `Program.cs` file***

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer.Sinks.MSSqlServer.Options;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var keyVaultUrl = builder.Configuration["KeyVault:Endpoint"];
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);

var secretValue = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync("managedinstance");

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Serilog");

var sinkOptions = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions()
{
    TableName = "SerilogLogs",
    AutoCreateSqlTable = false
};

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Information()
                      .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, sinkOptions, null, null, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
                      .CreateLogger();
    Log.Information("Connection to SQL logging store could not be established");
}
else
{
    Log.Logger.Error("Connection to SQL logging store could not be established.");
}

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); 
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" Version="6.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```
{
  "KeyVault": {
    "Endpoint": "https://YourKeyVaultName.vault.azure.net/"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Serilog": "@AzureKeyVault(managedinstance)"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "@Configuration:GetConnectionString('SqlDbConnection')",
          "tableName": "SerilogLogs"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyAppName"
    }
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]