# How to access Azure Key Vault with disabled public access from AppService?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am trying to access key that is stored in Azure Key Vault from AppService.

1. I have disabled Vault public access.
2. I have enabled Managed Identity for my Azure App Service.
3. I have granted that Managed Identity access to the Key Vault.
4. I have checked 'Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall' in the 'Firewalls and virtual networks' tab in Key Vault

Both AppService and Vault are located under one subscription, one region, etc.

I was hoping that these steps(especially #4) will be sufficient to get the key, but I get the exception

```cs
"ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: '@microsoft.keyvault(secreturi'."
```

Is there a way how to get the key from the Azure Key Vault(with disabled public access) from AppService without getting into private networks/endpoints, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your Code and `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: What is the Framework of your Application?

Comment: @Harshitha It is ASP.NET core web app. Which parts of the code are you interested in?

Comment: We cannot retrieve the Secret by disabling the `public access` [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEWVj.png) Instead we can retrieve the secrets by storing the KeyVault reference in the Application Settings of the Deployed App Service

Comment: Instead of disabling the public access completely, we can go with second option which allows us the specified client IP by selecting the Virtual Network.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned,

- Even I have disabled the Key Vault public access.
  [image]
- Enabled Managed Identity and also granted `Managed Identity` access to the Key Vault.

Initially I got the below error, when I tried to fetch the Secrets from Key Vault locally.

[image]

AFAIK,  `'@microsoft.keyvault(secreturi'." )` works only in the deployed  `Azure App Service` => `Configuration`.

***Check the below workaround to retrieve the Secret from KeyVault by adding the KeyVault Reference in Configuration Section.***

In App Service, select the User Create a Managed Identity
***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*", 
  "KeyVaultName": "harshukv18july",
  "SecretKV": "DummyValue"

}
```

***`Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
      new Uri($"https://{builder.Configuration["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
      new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

After deploying the App, add the new `Application Setting` with the same name as in `appsettings.json` (secret name - SecretKV).

[image]

Here my secret name is `SecretKV`, so added the same Application Setting in `Azure App Service`.

***Use the below code to fetch the secret value from `Azure KeyVault` in `.NET Core`.***

***`.csproj` file:***

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In `.cshtml`, add the below line to dispaly the secret.

```cs
<h2>Secret with KeyVault Reference - @myconfig["SecretKV"]</h2>
```

The above configuration works only when deployed in App Service by enabling `Public Access` or by creating the `Private endpoint`.

Another option can be by selecting the below.

- You need to add the `Virtual Network` and `Client IP` for the specified users.

[image]

To get the Secret locally refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454780/how-to-access-keyvault-secret-values-from-within-startup-cs-for-serilog-sql-sin/75506163#75506163), when `public access` to the KeyVault  is enabled.

Comment: Hi, Harshitha. Sorry for the late reply. Your answer doesn't directly answer my question, but it has helped me to understand this mechanism better. Thank you for your time and help!:)